# Error joining AAD: 80180014

Tags: windows-10, azure-activedirectory

I have a laptop running Windows 10 Pro Education (Version 21H1, Build 19043.1586) that I want to connect to my school. However, when connecting to AAD I get the server error code 80180014 without fail.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found this webpage that should offer some help.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/memdocs/blob/main/memdocs/autopilot/troubleshoot-device-enrollment.md

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1154736)